# Which template file does avada use for the blog post loop

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

Can someone please point me in the right direction regarding the location of the template file that contains the blogs posts loop I’m using the blog element.

I've tried multiple files but it does not work, Would ideally like to add a link after the meta information

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Kind redards

Comment: Hi and welcome to stackoverflow. Sorry, but SO is not a code-writing or tutoring service. We can help solve specific, technical problems, not open-ended requests for code or advice. Please edit your question to show https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist, and what specific problem you need help with. See the https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask page for details on how to best help us help you.

Comment: nowhere am I asking for code or to be tutored I'm asking for a possible location of the template file that contains the post loop this question was directed as people who might have worked with the avada theme.

Answer (score 0):

Check index.php,archive.php,search.php files, find function method that used here to display posts, search for this method (or use IDE to find it fast) in theme directory files, in this method you will find how theme load template files. Avada is a complex theme with a lot of settings and different templates files for loop, that can load different templates dynamically depended on your current theme settings for design and layouts.